# Hide or disable a button if the sheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba

For my form I need to hide or disable a textbox with a on-click delete macro attached to it when the sheet is protected. I'm talking about excel's build-in  protection system. I've looked at several tutorials but I can't seem to get it to work properly.
I tried multiple things including this:

```
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
    TextBox1.Visible = False
Else
    TextBox1.Visible = True
End If
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Any errors that come up or anything?

Comment: Yes I'm getting a error which I didn't notice earlier. Error 424, object required. I think its not recognizing the textbox somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
    TextBox1.Visible = False
Else
    TextBox1.Visible = True
End If
```

To

```
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
    ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Visible = False
Else
    ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Visible = True
End If
```

You are not declaring where the textbox is. This will fix it

Comment: I'm now getting error 438 'object doesn't support...' does this mean I'll have to use a actual button for example?

Comment: It should work with any object that has a visible property. The code works fine for me when I put a textbox in a brand new book

Comment: I've tried it with pictures, wordart, textboxes but it keeps telling me it isn't supported :/

Comment: Maybe try `Sheets("sheetname").TextBox1.Visible = False` with sheetname being the name of the sheet the textbox is on. Check the  textbox's properties to see if it's named TextBox1? Worst case scenario. You could create a new Excel file and try the code. Maybe something went corrupt in your file.

Comment: I would of suggested doing the `Sheets("sheetname")` however since the code is based on the activesheet, I can assume it was ran from the sheet with the objects involved. So should find the items as long as they are in the sheet. One thing to check is to make sure the names of the objects havent changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether the textbox is embedded in the worksheet or in a userform.

If in the worksheet is it a text box based on a shape? These are created from the INSERT tab on the Ribbon.

Or is this an ActiveX textbox? These are created from the DEVELOPER tab on the Ribbon.

If on the other hand, you are referring to a textbox on a userform then you can use the following code (assuming the userform code name is UserForm1):

```
UserForm1.Controls("NameOfYourTextBox").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.ProtectContents
```